# Trouble updating my database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a website which users can login and register. Now, I want the users to update their profile. I have trouble updating my database. My table name is "members." Nothing happens whenever I submit the form.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$value1 = $_POST['year'];
$value2 = $_POST['astatus'];
$value3 = $_POST['address'];
$value4 = $_POST['phone'];
$value5 = $_POST['email'];
$newpass = $_POST['pass'];
$newpass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
$user=$_SESSION['sess_user'];



        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'password') or die(mysqli_error());
        //Select DB From database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "database") or die("Database Error");
        //Selecting database

        $update_user="UPDATE '".members."' SET year='".$value1."', astatus='".$value2."', address='".$value3."', phone='".$value4."', email='".$value5."', pass='".$newpass."' WHERE '".user."'='".$user."'";

                if(isset($_SESSION["editerror"])){
                session_destroy(editerror);
                }

                session_start(editsuccess);
                $_SESSION["editsuccess"] ="Your student profile has been successfully updated.";
                header("Location:profile.php");











}
else{
echo "error";
}


?>
```

Comment: You never execute your horribly [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerable query. All you do is connect to the db, define a var with some sql in it, and then quit. Plus. `member` and `user`? Undefined constants? or variables missing their `$`?

Comment: You create your query, but never run it. Also - you're creating it by adding the variables directly into the SQL, and that opens you up for SQL injection. Look into using a prepared statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : Alwayes use mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

---

Use prepare statement when updating

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

you forget to execute query

```
    $update_user="UPDATE `members` SET `year`='".$value1."', `astatus`='".$value2."', `address`='".$value3."', `phone`='".$value4."', `email`='".$value5."', `pass`='".$newpass."' WHERE `user` ='".$user."'";   


        if ($conn->query($update_user) === TRUE) {
             session_start(editsuccess);
            $_SESSION["editsuccess"] ="Your student profile has been successfully updated.";
            header("Location:profile.php");

        } else {
           echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }
```

> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

start a `session` at the top of your page

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$value1 = $_POST['year']; 
....
```

And where is your `mysqli_query()`

run your `query`

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $update_user) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

your `query` is also wrong use this one

```
$update_user="UPDATE members  SET year='".$value1."', astatus='".$value2."', address='".$value3."', phone='".$value4."', email='".$value5."', pass='".$newpass."' WHERE user ='".$user."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$update_user="UPDATE '".members."' SET year='".$value1."', astatus='".$value2."', address='".$value3."', phone='".$value4."', email='".$value5."', pass='".$newpass."' WHERE '".user."'='".$user."'";
```

should be

```
$update_user = "UPDATE members SET year='" . $value1 . "', astatus='" . $value2 . "', address='" . $value3 . "', phone='" . $value4 . "', email='" . $value5 . "', pass='" . $newpass . "' WHERE user = '" . $user . "'";
```

Also you must not pass those values like that to the database. You must escape them properly to prevent database injection.